# Подсчитать количество символов идущих подряд в серии

Tags: python, pandas

Нужно подсчитать количество символов идущих подряд в серии pandas, но без помощи циклов.

К примеру, есть:

```
pd.Series([1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,8,8,8,8,1,1,2,3,3,3])
```

результат вывода должен быть список [5 6 4 2 1 3]

Comment: вопросы без ваших попыток решения будут закрываться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте сравнение со сдвигом и подсчет значений:

```
s = pd.Series([1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,8,8,8,8,1,1,2,3,3,3])
res = (s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).value_counts().sort_index().to_list()
```

res:

```
[5, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Можно сделать чуть короче (без лишней пересортировке) и, главное, понятнее: `res = s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).size().to_list()`

Comment: Замена `s.ne(s.shift())` на `s.diff().ne(0)` укоротит выражение еще на 1 символ :)